# android Handle JSONArray and parsing

Tags: android, parsing, arrays

Hi friends how to handle the Single JSON Array, I am having a data class which contain set and getURL method. the simple json array is:

```
"tril" [
         "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hsTOC-wD-mk&feature=g-logo"
         "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cHhZwvdRR5c&feature=related"
         "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l4QWxw655z0&feature=related"
       ]
```

My code is:

```
JSONArray trailerArray = innerJson.getJSONArray(Constant.tril);
for(int i = 0; i < trailerArray.length(); i++) {
    String videoUrl = Constant.VIDEO_URL+trailerArray.getString(i);
    similarData.setMov_trail(videoUrl);
}
```

similar data is my data class, i am not able to get all the three videos. i am only getting the last video url how to handle this.

Answer (score 2):

The format of the JSON array is not correct, it should be:

```
{
    "tril" :
    [
         "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hsTOC-wD-mk&feature=g-logo",
         "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cHhZwvdRR5c&feature=related",
         "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l4QWxw655z0&feature=related",
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for editing do you have any solution for this how can i get the exact data

Comment: Where do you want to get them to?

Comment: I used data class for getting and setting the data. while setting the data it is storing only last url. i want to use only the first url.

Comment: so instead of the for loop, just call `String videoUrl = Constant.VIDEO_URL+trailerArray.getString(0);
similarData.setMov_trail(videoUrl);`